# Coldfusion - Creating SOAP Web Service

Tags: web-services, soap, coldfusion

Here is the XML format that I'm trying to create a web service for:

```
  <test a1="a1">
     <e1>e1</e1>
     <e2 a2="a2">
        <e3>e3</e3>
        <e3>e3</e3>
     </e2>
  </test>
```

My problem is that I don't know how to create a Coldfusion (cfcomponent) SOAP web service that would conform to the XML format.

This is what I have come up with:

```
   <cfcomponent style="document" wsversion = 1 >
        <cffunction name="test" returntype="String" access="remote">
            <cfargument type="String" required="no" name="e1"/>
            <cfargument type="xml" required="no" name="e2" />
            <cfreturn "ok">
        </cffunction>
    </cfcomponent>
```

As you can see, a1,a2 and e3 are left out as I have no idea how to define them in the cffunction, and I'm not sure if making e2 as xml type is correct.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you may need to go through CF documentation http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-78b4.html

Comment: Thanks, but the reason I'm posting this is that I can't seem to find any documentation or articles regarding what I'm trying to achieve. It seems Coldfusion only supports very basic format of SOAP web services.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use

```
<cfsavecontent variable="textxml">
 <cfoutput>      
   <test a1="a1">
     <e1>e1</e1>
     <e2 a2="a2">
       <e3>e3</e3>
       <e3>e3</e3>
     </e2>
   </test>
  </cfoutput>
 </cfsavecontent>
```

and pass the testxml variable to the function as xml type argument.

```
<cfinvoke method="test" component="compname" xmltest="#textxml#">
```

no need to send seperate arguments e1 e2...can send testxml variable to the function.

```
<cfcomponent >
    <cffunction name="test" returntype="String" access="remote">
        <cfargument type="xml" required="no" name="xmltest" />
        <cfset newXML = XMLParse(arguments.xmltest)>
        <cfdump var="#newXML#">
        <cfreturn "ok">
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but what I'm looking for is a way to create a SOAP web service using properly defined schema, by that I mean the web service will describe (via wsdl) and validate (via SOAP request)  the schema. Your suggestion will not describe nor validate the schema.